# I am getting " WARN | url: (homepage) The URL is not reachable." on iOS pod lib lint command?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, cocoapods, podspec

When I am adding my private repo name in homepage url in .podspec file I am getting following warning,

```
WARN  | url: The URL (https://github.com/username/repo_name) is not reachable.
```

I can't figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

`pod lib lint --private`

to skips checks that apply only to public pods.

> NOTE: You will still be able to see the warnings but your validation will pass once all public warnings have been fixed.

Comment: I am still getting warning that URL is not reachable but also validation is passed?

Comment: Makes sense - it's just a warning.

Comment: yeah but while pushing I am getting path issue because URL is not reachable

Comment: I am getting following error while pushing .podspec file 
Validating spec - ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error ([!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/username/reponame.git /var/folders/b_/rksnr1hx58d18gf9w3mtby_m0000gn/T/d20200107-13659-1lh0ciy --template= --single-branch --depth 1 --branch 0.1.0

Cloning into '/var/folders/b_/rksnr1hx58d18gf9w3mtby_m0000gn/T/d20200107-13659-1lh0ciy'...
warning: Could not find remote branch 0.1.0 to clone.
fatal: Remote branch 0.1.0 not found in upstream origin
) during validation.
[!] The `.podspec` specification does not validate.

Comment: Did you do `git tag 0.1.0` and then `git push --tags` ?

Comment: I tried `git tag 0.1.0` and then `git push --tags` but no difference.

Comment: Do you see the `0.1.0` tag on the remote?